# What is the name of these flowering trees in Sydney, Australia?

Tags: identification

These trees seem to be in full blossom right now. They bear pale yellow colour flowers and draw a lot of bees to them.

I have not seen these kind of tree before. What is its scientific and common names?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Unfortunately I have not visited the place since so I can only add an enlarged portion of the original shot as an additional information

[image]

Comment: can you get a closeup photo of the flowers and foliage please? The ones you've posted don't magnify well - detail cannot be seen.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not visited the place since, so I added an enlarged portion of the original shot. If it did not help, i will take another one Dec this year.

Comment: Can't be sure, but possibly either a Melaleuca or a Callistemon variety; the leaves don't look particularly like either though, they seem to be somewhat too small for either of these from the fuzzy image you've posted...

Comment: http://anpsa.org.au/c-sali.html has a nice close-up picture of Callistemon salignus (syn. Melaleuca salicina) showing very thin, almost needle-like leaves. They say it is also called "Willow Bottlebrush".

Answer (score 1):

From these pictures alone (please tell us where in the world these trees were!), my best guess is *Melaleuca alternifolia*, the narrow-leaved paperbark (tea tree). The characteristics that suggest this include:

- Rough, peeling texture of the bark
- Bristle-like, dense evergreen leaves
- Long white inflorescences, many pointing upward rather than hanging down.

Answer (score 0):

Though you could have uploaded better quality images, still from what i can tell, they might be buckinghamia trees. The spikey look along with the colour and the tubular shape of the flowers resemble alot to the flowers you'll find on a buckinghamia tree when its in bloom.

Comment: I think the inflorescence shape is very similar to buckinghamia trees, but the bark on the trees in this post has a completely different texture.